# The distribution of 2 gamma random variables

Tags: probability-theory, gamma-distribution

If we have that both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are gamma(r,$\lambda$) distributed where $\lambda$ is the rate
so the density is $\Gamma(r)^{-1}\lambda^rx^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x}$.
What is the distribution of $-(aX_1+bX_2)$, where both a and b are positive constants.

My thought was that $aX_1 \sim gamma(r,a\cdot\lambda)$ and $bX_2 \sim gamma(r,b\cdot\lambda)$  by using the "scaling-property" but then I get stock because, I dont know how the sum of them is distributed (with a minus sign).

Comment: If $a=b$, the sum is gamma; for $a \ne b$, wikipedia has [some papers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Summation) to look at. (The effect of the minus sign should be obvious.)

Comment: So what is the distribution when a is not equal b? Cant find out